# ggplot: How to show density instead of count in grouped bar plot with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataframe consists of two factor variables: `cls` with 3 leveles and `subset` with 2 levels. I want to compare how much of each class (`cls`) is there in both groups of `subset`. I want to show percentages on y-axis. They should be computed within certain `subset` group, not whole dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
data = data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  cls = factor(c(rep("A", 200), rep("B", 300), rep("C", 500))),
  subset = factor(c(rep("train", 900), rep("test", 100)))
)
```

This was my attempt to show percentages, but it failed because they are computed within whole dataset instead of `subset` group:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = cls, fill = cls)) + geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~subset)
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

**Edit related to the accepted answer**:

```
plot_train_vs_test = function(data, var, subset_colname){
  plot_data = data %>% 
    count(var, eval(subset_colname)) %>% 
    group_by(eval(subset_colname)) %>% 
    mutate(perc = n/sum(n))
  
  ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = var, y = perc, fill = var)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
    facet_wrap(~eval(subset_colname))
}

plot_train_vs_test(data, "cls", "subset")
```

Results in errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option and easy fix would be to compute the percentages outside of ggplot and plot the summarized data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000),
  cls = factor(c(rep("A", 200), rep("B", 300), rep("C", 500))),
  subset = factor(c(rep("train", 900), rep("test", 100)))
)

data_sum <- data %>%
  count(cls, subset) %>%
  group_by(subset) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n))

ggplot(data_sum, aes(x = cls, y = pct, fill = cls)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  facet_wrap(~subset)
```

[image]

**EDIT** One approach to put the code in a function may look like so:

```r
plot_train_vs_test <- function(.data, x, facet) {
  .data_sum <- .data %>%
    count({{ x }}, {{ facet }}) %>%
    group_by({{ facet }}) %>%
    mutate(pct = n / sum(n))

  ggplot(.data_sum, aes(x = {{ x }}, y = pct, fill = {{ x }})) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{ facet }}))
}

plot_train_vs_test(data, cls, subset)
```

[image]

For more on the details and especially the `{{` operator see [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), [Programming with ggplot2](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#programming) and [Best practices for programming with ggplot2](https://dewey.dunnington.ca/slides/rstudioconf2020/#1)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. Do you know how to make it a function so that it can be applied to different dataframes with different names of `cls` and `subset` columns? I've tried but I don't understand something about how evaluation in R works (my code is in edited question)

Comment: Sure. See my edit for one approach and some references.